# Simulating physical key events in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard, uibutton, simulate

I need to create `UIButton` above `UIWebView` in `iOS SDK`, when user press this button it simulates `UIWebView` a physical keyboard key pressed, in the best situation, arrow keys.

Comment: any solution/update on this?